# Not debugging to device Xamarin

Tags: debugging, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have "little" problem with Xamarin plugin for Visual Studio Community 2015. When I choose "Start debugging (F5)", app debugging to moment when on status bar I see text "Ready" and after 30 min nothing happend. In console "output" is text "Detecting installed packages...". Application won't debugg on my device. Yesterday works fine. Any sugestion? Thank you for help.

UPDATE

I need to repair Visual Studio and it fix my problem. Debugging works fine.

Comment: Without collecting any detailed tracing, nobody can easily answer your question, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/

Comment: @coldzero, have you tried uninstalling the app from your device, and then trying to deploy again?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Cleaning the Solution and Rebuilding? If so, delete all files and folder in your project's `bin` and `obj` files, then do another clean and rebuild of the solution.

Finally I would check your references for any with a yellow icon. If you find yellow icons next to them, it is probably a package issue.

Comment: It won't help. I do everything what you tell me. In references there are no yellow icons and in components there are no errors. Any sugestions more?

Comment: I create clean project (Hello World) and I can't debugg it on my device

Comment: Like @LexiLi said, without any logs/tracing info, I have no idea